# How to check if a foreground is surrounded by certain color?

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I want to check if a foregrond is surrounded by a certain color (int this case it's green) or if surrounded by enough pixels of a certain color.

I have the image and it's mask (below are 2 examples):
[image][image]
[image][image]

I inverted the mask, converted the image surrounding the object to HSV color space and filtered by the green color:

```
Rect ballBBox = boundingRect(contour);
Mat ballMask(mask, ballBBox);
Mat ballImg(img, ballBBox);
Mat imgSurroundingBall;
Mat ballMaskInv;
bitwise_not(ballMask, ballMaskInv),
ballImg.copyTo(imgSurroundingBall, ballMaskInv);
Mat imgSurroundingBallHSV;
cvtColor(imgSurroundingBall, imgSurroundingBallHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

Scalar greenLower = Scalar(35, 100, 20);
Scalar greenUpper = Scalar(70, 255, 255);
Mat areaAroundBall;
inRange(imgSurroundingBallHSV, greenLower, greenUpper, areaAroundBall);
```

and the result is:
[image][image]
[image][image]

Below are examples when an object is not surrounded by green:
[image][image][image][image]
[image][image][image][image]

One of the ideas that I had was to find contour (after dialating the images) that is similar to `ballMask` and `areaAroundBall` images. But, it didn't work well since I still had a lot countours and couldn't find similar ones.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide some raw images? People are not very likely to help, if they first have to crop images.

Comment: @HansHirse, done. I've updated my post with the real png images.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?